# How do I get my IEnumerable<T> extension methods on an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, ienumerable

I really love using the IEnumerable extension methods.

But sometimes I end up with some collection that only implements IEnumerable and so they aren't available. What is the easiest way to convert the collection to a form where I can use these methods?

And more generally, could someone explain to me exactly what the difference is between these two types and the history behind why these methods exist for the newer IEnumerable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, use [`Cast()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) or [`OfType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx). Both convert a non-generic `IEnumerable` to a generic one with the specified element type - the difference being how they convert each element. `Cast` will cast each element, which means it throws an exception if you ask it to perform a conversion it can't handle. `OfType` simply skips elements which aren't of the right type.

For more information, see the [Edulinq blog post about these operators](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/13/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-33-cast-and-oftype.aspx).

As for the difference between the two types - the non-generic one existed before generics, basically, and is therefore not typesafe; the `Current` property of `IEnumerator`  is just `object` instead of a specific type. (Additionally, `IEnumerator` doesn't implement IDisposable, whereas `IEnumerator<T>` does.) If you're new to generics, that's more than can easily be covered in an answer here...

Answer (score 1):

To go from `IEnumerable` to an `IEnumerable<T>` you could use either the [`Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) or the [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx).

As far as why there are two.  `IEnumerable` existed since initial .NET 1.0 days.  Although the CLR internally supported typed collections, they were not exposed in C# (or VB.NET).  So when they were exposed the `System.Collections.Generics` namespace was added with `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score -1):

The `IEnumerable` interface already existed before generic collections from the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, including `IEnumerable<T>`, were added to the .NET Framework 2.0.

You can cast your non-generic collection to a generic one using the `MakeGeneric()` extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<object> MakeGeneric(this IEnumerable nonGenericCollection)
    {
        return nonGeneric.Cast<object>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this any better than just calling `Cast<object>` directly?

Comment: @JonSkeet: It's better for the sake of readability if you turn it into an extension method.

Comment: But `Cast` is **already** an extension method... and calling `foo.MakeGeneric` isn't as clear as calling `foo.Cast<object>` to my mind.

Comment: It may disguise **how** the collection is made generic, but it is way better to **read**.

Comment: I disagree completely. Cast should be familiar to all Lina programmers, unlike this; it's inflexible as it's hardcoded to `object`; the return type is less clear than being specific. Calling Cast directly takes no more space but communicates more information and acts more flexibly.